# Visualization of higher Bruhat order B(5,2)

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, polyhedra

I made the following images of the higher Bruhat order B(5,2) (in the sense of Manin/Schechtman) with vZome:

- [image 1](https://ibb.co/1f2xDry)
- [image 2](https://ibb.co/YQZ33wf)
- [image 3](https://ibb.co/D1hTnNy)

Unfortunately, in vZome its not possible do have regular octagons, so I would like to build it with Stella. As far as I understood, you can't build polyhedra from scratch in Stella, but you have to form them out of basic compounds. Is that correct? If so, then what would be the basic compounds in my case? Sorry for the naive question, I really have no intuition for polyhedra at all.

Comment: this seems more like a software question than a math question...

Comment: admittedly, part of it, yes.. (the math part is basically: do you understand this polyhedron?) i was hoping to find the experts for this specific type of software in a math forum, but if you would like to close it, it's okay with me

Comment: So you just need that graph with regular octagons? Because I have the code to generate the graph in SAGE, but with no control over the octagons. I'm not sure if that helps you. Anyway, let me know if you are interested in the code.